# How to curry a ... argument by position in R?

Tags: r, currying

This may fall under "you can't, and there's no reason to anyway," but I'm curious if it's possible.  At very least, maybe it will be a fun R puzzle.

I was pondering currying `cat` to always append `\n`.  However, `cat` is written so that it pastes together as many arguments as it is given (via `...`).

Surprisingly, this works:

```
> library(functional)
> catnip <- Curry( cat, "\n" )
> catnip("hi")

 hi
```

However, the `\n` winds up before the user's text.  Is there any way to curry the function such that you specify the curried argument always ends the `...` arguments?

Comment: Nifty answers all.  My mastery of `do.call` is incomplete but progressing.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like `Curry()` pretty effectively hardwires the two argument lists in the opposite order from what you'd like. It's a simple enough function though, that you can just construct its mirror image, and use it instead.

```
Curry2 <- function(FUN, ...) {
    .orig = list(...)
    function(...) do.call(FUN, c(list(...), .orig))
}

catnip <- Curry2( cat, "\n" )
catnip("hi")
```

Answer (score 7):

**#1.  Ignore the second argument of Curry and hard code the newline**

Try this which curries the last argument of `cat` by hard coding it in an anonymous function.  It does not actually make use of `Curry` arguments after the first:

```
catnip <- Curry(function(...) cat(..., "\n") )
```

**#2. Manufacture function by currying an anonymous function**

Here is a second solution which curries the last argument of `cat` by using an anonymous function which reorders `cat`'s arguments.

```
catnip2 <- Curry(function(last.arg, ...) cat(..., last.arg), "\n")

# test
catnip2("hi", "there")
```

**#3. Manufacture desired function by currying an even more basic function**

Perhaps the real point of all this is to see how we can take basic components and Curry them to get what we want.  Thus we could define a general `last.arg.fun` and then manufacture the desired function by a curry of it:

```
last.arg.fun <- function(FUN, last.arg, ...) FUN(..., last.arg)
catnip3 <- Curry(last.arg.fun, cat, "\n")

# test
last.arg.fun(cat, "\n", "hi", "there")

# test
catnip3("hi", "there")
```

We could do it in two steps if we needed `last.arg.cat` at some point:

```
last.arg.cat <- Curry(last.arg.fun, cat)
catnip4 <- Curry(last.arg.cat, "\n")

# test
last.arg.cat("\n", "hi", "there")

# test
catnip4("hi", "there")
```

Note that each of the tests should produce a line saying hi there ended in a newline.

EDIT: more solutions.